# SVG color fill on hover using Tailwind

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css

I've been trying to get my svg to fill in with black on hover but can't seem to do it.

I want it to have black outline like this
[image: my person svg].
And then fill like this [image: filled in svg].

This is the code I would expect to work to fill it in on hover. However, it doesn't quite work. If I take the `hover:` off of `hover:fill-current` then it just fills in black the whole time.

```
<svg class="h-6 w-6 text-black hover:fill-current" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
        d="M16 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zM12 14a7 7 0 00-7 7h14a7 7 0 00-7-7z" />
</svg>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1- By default only responsive variants are generated for fill utilities. So, we need to create the required variation to activate `:hover` state for `fill-current` class.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
    },
  },
  variants: {
    fill: ['hover', 'focus'], // this line does the trick
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

2- Consider to use a color class to obtain the exact result.

```
<svg class="h-6 w-6 text-black hover:fill-current hover:text-black" ... />
</svg>
```

[Working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/f8sjtJ2xNN)

##### Reference

[Fill - Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/fill)

Comment: its working my code..
`variants: {
    fill: ['hover', 'focus'], // this line does the trick
  },`

Answer (score 6):

### Styling based on parent state

You can use `group` modifier if you can/want to rely on parent state. Add `"group"` to parent element class and `"group-hover:fill-black"` to svg class.

```html
<div class="group text-black">
  <svg class="h-6 w-6 group-hover:fill-black" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
          d="M16 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zM12 14a7 7 0 00-7 7h14a7 7 0 00- 
 7-7z" />
  </svg>
  <p class="group-hover:text-amber-500">Hello color</p>
</div>
```

In above example there is a div with icon and text. On div hover icon fills with black and text change color to orange (amber-500).

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you put these props in the SVG tag under path
Here is the syntax. now whatever you want, like using group hover or simple hover, will work.

```
 <svg> 
    <path     
    fill-rule="evenodd"
    clip-rule="evenodd"/> 
    </svg>
```